# Getting all properties of a typescript class, even when they are implicitly undefined

Tags: typescript, class, properties

I'm currently trying to get an array with the property names of a class dynamically. However as it seems it is only possible to get explicitly undefined properties and properties which have a value.

Here is an example:

```
class foo {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop1ExplicitlyUndefined: string = undefined;
    prop2ExplicitlyUndefined: number = undefined;
    prop1WithValue: string = 'Hello World!';
    prop2WithValue: number = 123;
}

const myObject = new foo();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject));
console.log(Object.keys(myObject));
```

Both console.log will output:

```
[
    "prop1ExplicitlyUndefined", 
    "prop2ExplicitlyUndefined", 
    "prop1WithValue", 
    "prop2WithValue"
]
```

Is there any way to get them without setting the properties to undefined or setting them in the constructor?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Types are removed when converting to javascript, so if a type is all there is, then there's nothing at runtime.

Comment: I was wondering if it may be possible with the type itself... there is "keyof type" but it seems to be impossible to get an array of strings out of it